# Optimizing all permutations of certain equations

Tags: optimization, automation, wolfram-mathematica, linear-programming

I'm solving an optimization problem in Mathematica.  I want to generate additional equations where a variable z_k is substituted with (z_k - 1) or (z_k + 1).

How can I automate this and add these equations into the Maximize[] function?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to consider asking future questions at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com, the dedicated SE site for Mathematica Q&A.

Comment: I didn't realize there was one for Mathematica.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining

```
vars = {z1, z2, z3, z4};
shifts = {-1, 0, 1};
```

one way to generate all the replacement rules is as follows : first make a list with all the possible new values for each variable (the `Outer` bit), then take all combinations picking one element from each list (using `Tuples`).

```
rules = Tuples[Outer[#1 -> #1 + #2 &, vars, shifts]];
```

Then you can do :

```
Union[eq12 /. rules]
```

`Union[]` is required because some transformations will not affect `eq12`.

Or you can define a function to do everything in one go :

```
generateAdditionalEqs[eq_, vars_, shifts_] := (eq /. 
  Tuples[Outer[#1 -> #1 + #2 &, vars, shifts]]) // Union
```